# Start CAAnimation when view is not in view hierarchy

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, caanimation

I have a UI component (a loading spinner) that has an endless animation:

```
class MySpinner: UIView {

...

override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        updateLayers()
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.animatedLayer)
        self.updateLayers()
        self.startAnimating()
}

private func updateLayers() {
        //Set up path, stroke color and such
        self.animatedLayer.frame = self.bounds
}

private func startAnimating() {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true) //disable automatic animations by iOS

        let endlessRotationAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        endlessRotationAnimation.values = [ 0.0, CGFloat(2.0 * .pi) ]
        endlessRotationAnimation.keyTimes = [ 0.0, 1.0 ]
        endlessRotationAnimation.repeatDuration = .infinity
        endlessRotationAnimation.duration = 1.0
        self.animatedLayer.add(endlessRotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")

        CATransaction.commit()
}

}
```

It turns out this is not working. I assume that if I call `startAnimating()` before the view is added to the window, iOS will immediately remove the animation. If I first add the view to the view hierarchy and then call `startAnimating()`, things start working.

Is there a way to prevent iOS removing my animation? Or is there some documentation about this behaviour, I couldn't find any?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue by overriding `didMoveToWindow`.

```
public override func didMoveToWindow() {
    super.didMoveToWindow()
    startAnimating()
}
```